# Avoid PuTTY SSH terminal to crash when disconnecting from server

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm connecting via SSH to a remote 'live' server where I have some bash scripts automated via the crontab.  When an error happens in some of the automation scripts within the server,  the connection to the server is killed.  This is fine to me, but the problem is that PuTTY closes the entire window, which is a behavior I don't want.

I have checked all around the Web, unfortunately the PuTTY site does not have a support page.

Under PuTTY's options I have tried all the menus expanding all options, but still I can't find the right one.  I would expect it to be under Window > behaviour.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Close Window on Exit" option in the Session panel.

[Documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit)

This was in one of the first hits when I googled "putty closes window when connection closes".